# Two or more Flexslider2 within Bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dom, flexslider, jquery-events

I have a problem creating a gallery page. I am using Bootstrap as a base an get on fine with it. I have looked at various sliders and carousels and have chosen Flexslider2 - it works great and looks great and is working great as a single slider.

However I now want to use 4 Flexsliders, one on each tab for a gallery page. Ok so I could have 4 pages but it would look better on just 1 page.

I am very new to Javascript but do know html (but not DOM). My example below is just setup for 2 Flexsliders for simplicity.

When my page fires the initial Flexslider is fine but when I switch tabs the second one isn't shown, there are no errors but when I put an alert on the screen as the second Flexslider is initialised it then shows. This is pointing to a DOM issue but I can't seem to find the solution.

HTML;

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span9"> 
  <section id="tabs">
    <div class="bs-docs-example">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
          <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
            <p>this is tab1 (0)</p>
            <section class="slider">
              <div id="slider1" class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">
                  <li> <img src="assets/gallery/slide1.jpg" /> </li>
                  <li> <img src="assets/gallery/slide2.jpg" /> </li>
                  <li> <img src="assets/gallery/slide3.jpg" /> </li>
                  <li> <img src="assets/gallery/slide4.jpg" /> </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div id="carousel1" class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">
                  <li> <img src="assets/gallery/slide1.jpg" /> </li>
                  <li> <img src="assets/gallery/slide2.jpg" /> </li>
                  <li> <img src="assets/gallery/slide3.jpg" /> </li>
                  <li> <img src="assets/gallery/slide4.jpg" /> </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
            <p>this is tab2 (1)</p>
            <section class="slider">
              <div id="slider2" class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">
                  <li> <img src="assets/gallery/slide2.jpg" /> </li>
                  <li> <img src="assets/gallery/slide3.jpg" /> </li>
                  <li> <img src="assets/gallery/slide4.jpg" /> </li>
                  <li> <img src="assets/gallery/slide1.jpg" /> </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div id="carousel2" class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">
                  <li> <img src="assets/gallery/slide2.jpg" /> </li>
                  <li> <img src="assets/gallery/slide3.jpg" /> </li>
                  <li> <img src="assets/gallery/slide4.jpg" /> </li>
                  <li> <img src="assets/gallery/slide1.jpg" /> </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="bs-docs-separator">
  </section>
</div>
</div>
```

And the javascript is;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("just about to call initflex");
    initflexsliders();
    $(this).tab('show');
})  
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).load(function(){
       initflexsliders();   
}); 
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function initflexsliders(){
          $('#carousel1').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlNav: false,
            animationLoop: false,
            slideshow: false,
            itemWidth: 100,
            itemMargin: 5,
            asNavFor: '#slider1'
          });

          $('#slider1').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlNav: false,
            animationLoop: false,
            slideshow: false,
            sync: "#carousel1",
          });
          $('#carousel2').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlNav: false,
            animationLoop: false,
            slideshow: false,
            itemWidth: 100,
            itemMargin: 5,
            asNavFor: '#slider2'
          });

          $('#slider2').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlNav: false,
            animationLoop: false,
            slideshow: false,
            sync: "#carousel2",
          });
       }
</script>
```

Has anyone got any ideas? I expect it is something simple but its got me pulling my hair out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Played around a little bit, and it seems that you should not initialize every slider on page load, instead just call it on each tab separately.

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qSqpD/709/

```
$('#myTab a:first-child').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).tab('show'); 
  $('#carousel1').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        itemWidth: 400,
        itemMargin: 5,
        asNavFor: '#slider1'
      });
  });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi uvgrin, many thanks for your help and it seems to be working. So what happens when I add another tab? I have created a jsfiddle based on yours and the third tab (doesn't matter what order I select them in)needs an extra click but once its loaded (initiated its great). There is something in the understanding that i'm just not getting here - again thanks for your time. Here's my fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/didsy/76Dkr/)

Comment: Hi uvgrin, I worked with your solution and got it firing all Flexsliders on all tabs so many thanks for your effort and your example. I used the a[href=""] functionality to fire off each.

Comment: Oh, yeah I missed that you have more tabs, anyhow I would suggest same thing as you did. glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

I have solution too, this works on flexslider 2.5

We catch event when tab already open and then init flexslider:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var selectedTab = $(e.target).attr("href") // activated tab
  if( $(selectedTab + ' .flexslider' ).length  ){

        $(window).trigger('resize'); //this should fix for you but you can also try this


        var carousel_sliders = $(selectedTab + ' .flexslider');

        for (var i = 0; i < carousel_sliders.length; i++) {
            var element = carousel_sliders.eq(i);
             element.flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                controlsContainer: $(selectedTab + " .custom-navigation-m .custom-controls-container"),
                customDirectionNav: $(selectedTab + " .custom-navigation-m a")
            });
        }



    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution.

Please go to

https://github.com/liangrongze/flexslider-compatible-bootstrap-tab

and download the flexslider file to replace your old js file.

It works in my project.

Answer (score 0):

A easy solution is:

In HTML:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="videos" align="center">
```

In JS:

```
$('#video').click( function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#slider2').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                animationLoop: false,
                slideshow: false,
                itemMargin: 5,
                video: true
            });
```